# Searching a large dictionary for duplicate values

Tags: python, dictionary, memory

I am currently creating a program which creates a random 15 digit string and finds the SHA-1 equivalent of the string.

As I convert the SHA-1 string and shorten it to the first 15 digits, I want to find any duplicate instances in my dictionary. If it does, it tells me the random string to which it is assigned.

As you can imagine this is taking forever to do. I understand that there are more efficient ways to do this such as a binary search or Pollard Rho technique or cycle finding but I am having difficulty in implementing this in Python.

This is what I have so far (Python):

```
for i in range (n):
    t=''.join([random.choice(alpha) for _ in range(15)])
    t=t.encode('utf-8')
    h=hashlib.sha1(t)
    h=(h.hexdigest()[0:15])
    if h in hashDict:
        print ("Duplicate found")
        sha1val=hashlib.sha1(hashDict[h])
        sha2val=hashlib.sha1(t)
        print (hashDict[h],":",sha1val.hexdigest())
        print (t,":",sha2val.hexdigest())
        break
    hashDict[h]=t
```

Comment: Is the code working or not?

Comment: Looking something up in a dictionary is generally O(1). Are you sure that's the bottleneck?

Comment: @Barmar: Perhaps the problem is in the value of `n`.

Comment: Try not performing expensive computations multiple times. You already do `hashlib.sha1(t)` when you assign `h`, don't repeat it when you assign `sha2val`. Save it in a variable the first time.

Comment: @Nurzhan the code works but takes a long time

Comment: @Gallieon474 benchmark it and find out which part is slowing it down, then optimize that.

Comment: @Barmar will amend

Comment: You mean `if h in hashDict` is slow?

Comment: @Gallieon474 What is the size of the hashDict?

Comment: @Gallieon474 And what is the size of n?

Comment: @Nurzhan sorry the dictionary is empty and n is 100000

Comment: @Barmar it's the process of searching

Comment: @Gallieon474 What is alpha?

Comment: @Nurzhan it's to create the random hex value which are characters stored in an array

Comment: @Gallieon474 I understand, how many characters in alpha?

Comment: @Nurzhan 0-9,A-F that's it

Comment: @Gallieon474 I ran this code on my machine. It takes 0.73 seconds. Is it long?

Comment: @Nurzhan really!!!!! I must be doing something wrong as it runs but a result is not output and it's been a day!

Comment: @Gallieon474 The code runs ok. If shorten the range of values in alpha (A - E only), then it even find the duplicates. But it runs fast.

Comment: @Nurzhan I'm trying to find the duplicate SHA-1 values and if I shorten the string to be SHA-1'd it presents me with the same hex string after a bit.

Comment: @Gallieon474 Anyway, my code runs fast and why yours runs so long is weird.

Comment: @Nurzhan so which values has it outputted?

Comment: I tried about dozen of times and no output. But it ran about 0.7 seconds on average.